# Xcode 7: Can't use CalendarUnitMonth in Swift 2.0, Xcode 7

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I am using swift2.

I used this code:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()             
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: theDate)
```

I am getting this error: **Could not find member 'CalendarUnitMonth**'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check Swift 2 documentation and search for `OptionSetType` (adopted by `NSCalendarUnit`). You can use it in this way:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Month, .Day], fromDate:NSDate())
```