# Swift 2.0 'Element.Protocol' does not have a member named 'Hour', NSCalendar.components

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I got a problem with Swift 2.0 and NSDateComponents.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components: NSDateComponents = calendar.components([.Hour,
    .Minute, .Second], fromDate: self.dateTime , toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)
```

I know since Swift 2.0 .Hour | .Minute can no longer be used so tried it with the new way with OptionSetType.

Like answered here: [Xcode 7: Can't use CalendarUnitMonth in Swift 2.0, Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168572/xcode-7-cant-use-calendarunitmonth-in-swift-2-0-xcode-7)

But it doesn't work. XCode gives me the following error: 
 'Element.Protocol' does not have a member named 'Hour'

Does anybode have an idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the error message, it appears that Xcode does not like your `options: nil`. Try using `[]` instead.

```
calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate(),
    toDate: NSDate(), options: nil) // error

calendar.components([.Hour], fromDate: NSDate(),
    toDate: NSDate(), options: []) // no error
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried everything because I thought the problem was the first parameter.. never thought about the last one!
Everything works fine now!